# Is it possible to configure where Vagrant stores its boxes?

Tags: vagrant

When you run

```
vagrant box add <some-box>
```

by default, it will store the box in

```
~/.vagrant.d/boxes/
```

Is it possible to specify a different directory for boxes to get stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the first part of the path `~/.vagrant.d` through the `VAGRANT_HOME` environment variable, described [here](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/other/environmental-variables.html)

If you'd like to keep using `~/.vagrant.d` but store just boxes in a different location maybe you could symlink the `boxes` directory